# Running Rscript System commands with openssl

Tags: r, rscript

I'm having a bit of an issue getting R to execute a system command for me.  The system command is `openssl` and it is very basic.

I'm on a Windows system.

If I execute the following code on either cmd.exe prompt or powershell, it works as expected:

```
## echo "the name of the dog is bruce" | openssl enc -base64
dGhlIG5hbWUgb2YgdGhlIGRvZyBpcyBicnVjZQo=
```

However, when I try to convert this back to the original string in my R script, it doesn't work:

```
mydata <- "dGhlIG5hbWUgb2YgdGhlIGRvZyBpcyBicnVjZQo="
system(sprintf("echo '%s' | openssl enc -base64 -d", mydata))
```

It complains about a `echo` not being found.

```
Warning message:
'echo' not found
```

I know that there are packages I can download, however, I would like to get this resolved using the base packages that come with R.  Since openssl doesnt appear to be part of the base, I'm resorting to the above method (which I know is not efficient so please take it easy on me).

I have tried:

```
system2(sprintf("echo '%s' | openssl enc -base64 -d", mydata))
```

and

```
shell(sprintf("echo '%s' | openssl enc -base64 -d", mydata))
```

None of which worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `shell()`, provide the full file path to openssl and it should work.  Note that you need to use the argument `intern = TRUE` so that it returns an R object that can be assigned.

```
mydata <- "dGhlIG5hbWUgb2YgdGhlIGRvZyBpcyBicnVjZQo="
shell(sprintf("echo %s | \"C:/Tools/openssl-1.1.1/openssl.exe\" enc -base64 -d", mydata), intern = TRUE)

[1] "the name of the dog is bruce"
```

For completeness, using the `openssl` library:

```
library(openssl)

str_enc <- base64_encode("the name of the dog is bruce")
rawToChar(base64_decode(str_enc))

[1] "the name of the dog is bruce"
```